# http streaming with netty and partial request

Tags: http, streaming, netty

I am trying to create an http server which will start sending responses as early as I receive the first chunk.

I get a voice sample and then I return something back for each chunk of the voice sample. I was able to do this and test it out with apache http client and it worked. But I can't seems to get curl working with this. I start sending `200 O.K` as as soon as I recieve the first chunk and the response starting from then on. And at the end of the request chunk I send an end of response chunk .Why does this not work with curl but with java http client.  I saw that curl is sending variable size chunks but this may not be the actual reason.

Please help.

Comment: Can I keep writing request chunks while I respond with chunks for each of the request chunk?

Comment: What will happen if I do this  ?  Send http request chunk by chunk . On server read the first chunk , write 200 OK , then for each input chunk write an output chunk and flush it to wire. I reach end chunk from input , I write end chunk to output .  Will this work?